# Is it possible to reference an AWS Lambda from itself?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, tags

I apologize if this question is unclear in any way - I will do my best to add detail if it is difficult to understand. I have an AWS Lambda, from which I would like to access the tags for that same lambda. I have found the listTags method for AWS Lambda, which appears to be what I am looking for. It can be called as follows:

```
 var params = {
  Resource: "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:123456789012:function:my-function"
 };
 lambda.listTags(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
 });
```

However, in order to use this function, we have to create a new instance of the lambda using the lambda constructor:

```
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda({apiVersion: '2015-03-31'});
```

I don't think that this is what I want to do. Instead, I want to have access to the tags for this particular lambda whenever the lambda is run. So, if I invoke the lambda, I want that invocation to be able to look and see that the lambda, itself, has a tag with the key "environment" and value "production," for example. I wouldn't think I would want to construct a new instance from within it... of itself.

Surely there has to be a way to do this? I may be missing something obvious. I've tried the code I've provided above using the context object in place of the lambda, but to no avail.

Comment: `AWS.Lambda` probably (?!) just instantiates an *API client*, it doesn't "instantiate a Lambda" (as in, execute an AWS Lambda function)…

Comment: @deceze Ah, ok. I am still very new to AWS. So, in this case, it would make sense to instantiate the API client for AWS.Lambda within the lambda itself?

Comment: If you wish to pass information to a Lambda function, I would recommend using the **Environment Variables** associated with the function rather than tags. They are directly accessible to the running function.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider Lambda Environment Variables.

AWS Tags simply is metadata used to organise resources, aws documents indicates their usage as:

```
- Tags for resource organization
- Tags for cost allocation
- Tags for automation
- Tags for access control
```

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_tagging.html